# Koajs how to send a json response

Tags: node.js, koa

I have this bit of code:

```
router.post('/register', function *(next) {
  User.create(this.request.body, function(err, data) {
    this.type = 'json';
    if (err) {
      return this.body = err;
    }
    return this.body = data;
  });
});
```

But I get a 404 error (I'm assuming it's because the `router.post` returns instantly and doesn't wait for the callback. How can I yield a response from the inside of the callback so that I don't get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you write your User model.  But you shouldn't use callback here.  And you can't yield in normal function as well.

This should work if you don't have `app.on('error')`.  If you do, you could remove the try catch block and just have `this.body = yield User.create(this.request.body)`

```
router.post('/register', function *(next) {
  try {
    this.body = yield User.create(this.request.body)
  } catch (err) {
    this.body = err
  }
})
```